# How to build (compile) .NET application with #include file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a .NET application on Visual Studio 2015. In the ASPX file, I have header block and footer block. These header and footer are files outside of the solution. So in my ASPX file I use this

```
<!--#include file="/includes/common-header.asp"-->
```

This will work just fine if I publish it but I can not do F5 (Build) before I publish.

Is there a way to build the solution with the Include File?

Comment: Sounds like you might want to look at master pages instead, as a different way of having a common header/footer.

Comment: Classic ASP, which is what you have in your includes, cannot be compiled since its interpreted at run time.  Whereas ASP.Net  pages i.e. aspx can be compiled. But if these classic ASP files are outside the solution as you have mentioned, then you need to follow certain steps in order to publish them, else they will not be automatically deployed with your aspx files.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not the answer, but, you can't copy/paste the header and the footer on the masterpage?

If the answer is no, and you are trying to debug this, the files are in the correct folder in the solution? Maybe the root when debug is on is different from the one in the IIS.